# PHPMailer do not work properly sometimes on gmail port 465 or 587 on localhost

Tags: phpmailer

I am using the latest version of **PHPMailer 6.0.2** on **LOCALHOST** with Gmail SMTP Ports [ **SSL on 465** and **TLS 587** ]. It works well but not stable or works properly, very strange while OpenSSL Extension is also active in PHP Config /PHP.ini file.

It returns the error " **SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host** ", sometimes on 465 or 587 port.

As right now it's on 587.

**Here the exact error on port 587 ;**

```
2017-12-05 13:00:26 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
2017-12-05 13:00:26 Connection: opened
2017-12-05 13:00:26 SMTP INBOUND: "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f3sm245851pgt.15 - gsmtp"
2017-12-05 13:00:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f3sm245851pgt.15 - gsmtp
2017-12-05 13:00:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [110.36.136.72]"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 35882577"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250-CHUNKING"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: "250 SMTPUTF8"
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [110.36.136.72]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-12-05 13:00:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP INBOUND: ""
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-12-05 13:00:27 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2017-12-05 13:00:27 Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting     
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

**HERE IS THE RELEVANT CODE:**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->Username = $from_address;
$mail->Password = $from_password;
$mail->SetLanguage("tr", "phpmailer/language");
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
$mail->Encoding = "base64";
$mail->SetFrom($from_address, $from_name);

foreach ($to_email_list as $to) {
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
}

$mail->AddReplyTo($from_address, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;

//Creating Email Body
$message = "<html>\n";
$message .= "<body>\n";
$message .= '<p>Greetings,</p>';
$message .= '<p>' . $email_message . '</p>';
$message .= "</body>\n";
$message .= "</html>\n";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "On Port: " . $from_smtp_port . " </br> Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!  on Port " . $from_smtp_port . "</br>";

   foreach($to_email_list as $list){
        echo $list . "</br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a TLS failure. Read and do what it says in the troubleshooting guide the error links to for how to diagnose and resolve it.

Comment: Thanks! can you please guide bit more?

Comment: Follow the link in the error message, do what it says.

Comment: Because, still unable to find the solution on troubleshooting guide. Please guide more.

Comment: Add to your question what happens when you use openssl to check the cert status. Show the status of your openssl extension in PHP. Show the results of making sure your CA file isn't outdated. I'm not about to simply retype what's in the guide; if you're not going to do what it says there, I've no reason to believe you'll do it when I say the same things here either.

Comment: Yeh i am on it. I am checking in troubleshooting guide

Comment: Will let you know if get any issue. Appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Help me too, i'm having the same issue here, already posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658650/gmail-smtp-cant-connect

Comment: Hi Synchro;
I have seen troubleshooting guide, it was very helpful but still i am unable to fix the issue properly, because.

1: Script is not working on localhost with Gmail Port 587 while it is working with 465 port on localhost.

2: But when I host this script on my domain then it works fine with Gmail port 587 but not with 465. 

Why its happening, can you please guide? 

Here is error of localhost;
2017-12-06 07:16:55 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-12-06 07:16:55 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution on [troubleshooting guide.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

I recommend to other users who are facing the same issue; please see following Points carefully on troubleshooting guide;
 - **Opportunistic TLS**
 - **PHP 5.6 certificate verification failure**
 - **cURL error 60**

My Script is working fine with Gmail ss/465 and tls/587.

Thanks! @Synchro.