# Gmail SMTP Can't Connect

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I can't get Gmail SMTP to connect and I'm getting this debug info on tls:

```
2017-12-05 16:40:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q9sm1085224pfl.116 - gsmtp
2017-12-05 16:40:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2017-12-05 16:40:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2405:204:d304:d69d:3c36:3d9:213e:186a]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2017-12-05 16:40:25 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2017-12-05 16:40:25 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2017-12-05 16:40:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-12-05 16:40:26
2017-12-05 16:40:26
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

I have tried SSL too, which says "can't connect". I have never had an experience like this.

Note: I am using PHPMailer

Does anyone have the same issues or is it just me ?

Comment: There has been a flurry of these reports over the last couple of days - it seems to be related to an update to the root certificates used by PHP - see [this issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1264). This is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). I can also tell from your debug output that you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so I suggest you upgrade while you're on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into my problem

Comment: $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
   'verify_peer' => false,
   'verify_peer_name' => false,
   'allow_self_signed' => true
   )
 );
I just configured mailer with this config, now its seems to be working fine. Is there any security issue by turning off the ''verify_peer" ?

Comment: Yes. It means that you're vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. Read the guide and that ticket to figure out exactly what the problem is; you should never need to set that option when talking to gmail; google doesn't publish bad certificates.